# Update Oracle table for multiple records

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle10g

I have couple of tables in my Oracle database as shown below

```
**IM_FP**
FP_ID
FP_NAME
FP_STATUS

**IM_FP_DTL**
FP_DTL_ID
FP_ID
IM_ID
FP_DATE

FP_ID    FP_NAME   FP_STATUS
1         ABC        TRUE
2         DEF        TRUE
3         GHI        TRUE
4         TEC        TRUE
5         KEC        TRUE

FP_DTL_ID         FP_ID   IM_ID     FP_DATE
1                  1        1        1-JAN-1996
2                  2        1       10-JAN-1996
3                  3        1        2-FEB-1996
4                  4        2        1-JAN-1996
5                  5        3        2-JAN-2010
```

There is a 1-1 relationship between both the tables. But the IM_ID can be duplicates in the FP_DTL table and update the FP_STATUS value in IM_FP table to false for all the records but True for the record with MAX(FP_DTL_ID).

For example in the above scenario, FP_STATUS in IM_FP table for the first two records will be FALSE and the third record will be TRUE

```
Select IM_ID from FP_DTL GROUP BY IM_ID HAVING COUNT(IM_ID)>1
```

will give me all the AM_ID that are duplicates.

Please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about:

```
UPDATE IM_FP
SET FP_STATUS = 'TRUE'
WHERE FP_ID IN
  (SELECT MAX(FP_DTL_ID)
   FROM   IM_FP_DTL
   GROUP BY IM_ID)
AND (FP_STATUS IS NULL OR FP_STATUS != 'TRUE');

UPDATE IM_FP
SET FP_STATUS = 'FALSE'
WHERE FP_ID NOT IN
  (SELECT MAX(FP_DTL_ID)
   FROM   IM_FP_DTL
   GROUP BY IM_ID)
AND (FP_STATUS IS NULL OR FP_STATUS != 'FALSE');
```